# WSFC Quorum query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups, windows-server

I have an three node AlwaysOn AG setup, running on SQL Server 2012 SP3 in Windows Server 2012 R2. Node 1 and Node 2 are in the same physical location. Node 2 is the secondary replica. Third node acts as a DR, in a different location.

I have setup this system without shared storage and it is running on VMs. For cluster quorom, I have not added a witness or file share which MSFT says it is recommended irrespective number of nodes in Windows Server 2012R2. Here in my case, number of nodes is 3 and for odd number of votes, quorom is node majority.

Is witness required in my scenario? What risks do I face here without witness?

The reason i'm asking this is because we had an Microsoft's assessment tool run in this setup which prompted that one of the critical observation in this that Witness or file share is not available. I'm trying to understand why it is a concern.

Recently, one of my nodes got evicted because of VM level issue, production was live only one of the nodes. Total votes was 2. Cluster did not go down. Now in what scenario this witness would have helped me? Considering I do not have a shared disk for AlwaysOn, I'm not in a situation to add a witness which should be a shared drive I suppose (correct me if I'm wrong).

Links that I referred to:

1. [This one says without witness, cluster will survive until last node](http://sqlha.com/2013/07/02/wsfcs-dynamic-witness-in-windows-server-2012-r2/)
2. [One from MSDN blog says that Always configure a witness irrespective of nodes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_press/2014/04/28/from-the-mvps-understanding-the-windows-server-failover-cluster-quorum-in-windows-server-2012-r2/)

Comment: You probably want to include details in your question about how you've tried it in a non-production environment and can't see any problems... or you've hit [x] problem and need [y] solution, etc. Add details to make this question answerable in a couple of paragraphs.  Add details about what you've looked at, the research you've done, the problems you're expecting, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Should you setup a witness? Yes, always with 2012R2+.

Why? WS2012R2 added dynamic witness on top of the already included dynamic quorum, both of which are enabled by default.

Dynamic witness and quorum work together to give you cluster the highest availability possible given the infrastructure it has.

How dynamic witness works is as follows:

- If there is a witness setup and there is an odd number of nodes/votes - no vote is given to the witness.
- If there is a witness setup and there is an even number of nodes/votes - the witness is given a vote.

This way there is always an odd number of votes which is ideal. Even if this is used, there are still scenarios in WS2012R2 that could cause the cluster to shut down due to quorum - many of these have been addressed with WS2016.

Comment: When dynamic witness is on by default, in my case 3 nodes are there. Majority is 2 and when one node goes down, cluster stays online, if two nodes goes down, because of DQ cluster will stay online right? it will stay online until last man standing correct? Where here file share witness is required?

Comment: You are correct, if and only if the nodes go down 1 at a time with some time in between them going down. The witness is required any time there would be a cluster event that would check for quorum. In this case it could potentially prevent the cluster from going offline.